# Cannot load modules Mod_authz_svn.so & Mod_dav_svn.so on-apache-2.4.10

Tags: apache, svn

I  am using Subversion-1.8.14  for apache-2.4.10 for a  Windows 2008 64-bit 
(Almost 99% it's the supported version for both applications)
I copied following two files from Subversion/bin to Apache/modules

- mod_dav_svn.so
- mod_authz_svn.so

I have edited Httpd.conf to add the Subversion reference to the end of the load modules section at the top and copied following lines:

```
LoadModule authz_svn modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dav_svn modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

as per the doc: `Xstore_POS_and_Xstore_Office_-_Build_Server_Setup`

```
# Configure Subversion repository
<Location /svn> 
DAV svn 
SVNPath "C:/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin/xyzxstorerepo" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName “Subversion Repository” 
AuthUserFile “htdocs/.htpasswd” 
AuthzSVNAccessFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/bin/xyzxstorerepo/conf/svn-acl-conf"
Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

The error reads

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>   >>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 111 of C:/Program Files (x86)/apache-2.4.10/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found."

How can I fix it.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If this has been solved by any means, can you please post the solution?